# App to check who is logging in and direct them to the correct page accordingly

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

The code I have below is for a simple Android login app that I built and what I want it to do is direct the user to a certain page if the login is correct, currently the user can login and look at their profile, however they're both directed to the same profile regardless of who they are. I have two Profile activity's NiallProfile.xml and AlannahProfile.xml, at present both get directed to NiallProfile but I want to change that so that if the credentials 'Alannah' and her password are entered it will direct to her page. Can someone show me how to do this? Preferably using an Intent if that is possible as I already know how to use them. The code below checks to see if login was successful and if it was, they're brought to Nialls profile

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "";
    if (type.equals("Login")) {
        try {
            String username = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "utf-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "utf-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (result.contains("Successful login")){
        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(context, NiallProfile.class);
        context.startActivity(profileIntent);
    } else {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you determine whether log-in is successful? Where do you get the Username and password? Post a bit more of code where you do those things and I will try to help you out.

Comment: The code takes username and password from an online database, I don't think that's the issue as both users can log in, I kept the PHP code out of this question so as to not confuse people, I just need some sort of check that says if(Username = 'Alannah' and result = 'Login successful') { Intent profile2Intent= new Intent(context, AlannahProfile.class

Answer (score 0):

In the part where you check `if ( username == "Alannah")`  store this variable somewhere where you can access it in your `onPostExecute`, or even better make your `onPostExecute` accept additional parameter, like `onPostExecute(String username, String results)`

And then just make a check:

```
 if (result.contains("Successful login")){
   if(username == "Alannah") {
        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(context, AlannahProfile.class);
        context.startActivity(profileIntent);
   } else {
        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(context, NiallProfile.class);
        context.startActivity(profileIntent);
   }

 } else {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
 }
```

If later you will support more users, consider using `switch` statement instead of `if-else`.

Comment: Okay thanks, I've added some additional code to show you how the login works, can you help me any further?

Comment: try to declare String username outside of doInBackground method and then only asign it with username = params[1];  .. in postExecute then do as I said. Let me if it lets you asign a value outside of doInBackground. You might need to declare static to your username.

Comment: It says username is never used

Comment: I think that is just a warning, because you are actually not using the username anywhere, only in IF statement later on, if you followed my example, but it is not considered as usage, your app should still run though.

Comment: It also gives an Override error 'method does not override method from its superclass'

Comment: Dont follow my example 1 to 1. Do not place String username as input paramter for onPostExecute. Leave it as you had it before. Just declare private static String username inside your class. Then inside you doInBackground ... username = params(1); .. and in your postExecute, use the username in if() as in example

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
String username = null;
```

outside your methods, so that this `variable` is accessible to all methods in class.

Then inside your `doInBackground()` method, assign it to global username variable.

Then in `onPostExecute()` check if login is successful and then check which user has logged in and redirect accordingly.